# How to convert jsonarray to string array using jackson in spring project

Tags: java, jackson

How to convert jsonarray to string array using jackson in spring

```
{"number":[5,3,6,7,9,8,10,11,12,13,14,15,19,26]}
```

this should convert to array[] of object using jackson

Comment: Your JSON is an array of numbers. Jackson will not convert numbers to Strings if they can be converted to integers.

Answer (score 1):

Beside the fact, that it doesn't seem useful to convert an array of numbers to an array of strings, jackson will read this without any problems:

```
String json = "{\"number\":[5,3,6,7,9,8,10,11,12,13,14,15,19,26]}";
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
MyObject object = mapper.readValue(json, MyObject.class);
```

Where `MyObject` looks like this:

```
private static class MyObject {
    private String[] number;

    public String[] getNumber() {
        return number;
    }

    public void setNumber(String[] number) {
        this.number = number;
    }
}
```

To get just the array you can use `mapper.readTree()` to get a JsonNode. After that you can extract the array and use the java stream API, to parse it:

```
String[] array = StreamSupport.stream(mapper.readTree(json).get("number").spliterator(), false)
        .map(JsonNode::asText)
        .toArray(String[]::new);
```

Comment: Is there any way to solve it without using class ex String [] number= new ObjectMapper().readValue(jsonString, String [].class);

Comment: @HemantKumar What do you want to use instead?!

Comment: just want to convert to String [] number without using class my above solution working for [5,3,6,7,9,8,10,11,12,13,14,15,19,26] but not for {"number":[5,3,6,7,9,8,10,11,12,13,14,15,19,26]}

Comment: Yes, because the second one is an object and not an array.

Comment: Problem is I don't want to write a new class for single property

Comment: @HemantKumar I updated my answer.

Comment: Yeah, this way we can use....Thanks a lot, Samuel

Comment: I'm glad you solved your problem. Feel free to [accept my answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) if you feel it was useful to you.